# Concatenate the index field from data driven pages into the file name during export?

Tags: arcpy, export, data-driven-pages

I am trying to modify this script form Esri to export my data driven pages to PNG format. I have two things I am trying to communicate in the file name, the priority (which is represented by the page number, easy enough) and the name of the cluster I am producing a map for. I tried introducing a variable using the index name by defining it with the `mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageNameField` function, but it is giving me an error, both when trying to run the script identifying it as a string and without.

Here is my code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
cluster = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageNameField
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
  mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Geodata\Cluster Priority Maps\RAN" + "Priority " + str(pageNum) + "_" + str(cluster) + ".png", resolution=150)
del mxd
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1228, in ExportToPNG
    layout.exportToPNG(*args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 626, in exportToPNG
    return self._arc_object.exportToPNG(*args)
AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in executing ExportToPNG
```

And here is the error I get when I use just the variable and not as a string:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Field' objects
```

How would I get this to run so that the index field value of the page gets written into the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what [`row`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/row.htm) you're up to, get the value of the `pageNameField` [`Field.name`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm) for that row:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageNameField.name

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
    cluster = row.getValue(pageName)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Geodata\Cluster Priority Maps\RAN" + "Priority " + str(pageNum) + "_" + str(cluster) + ".png", resolution=150)
del mxd
```

Comment: Looks like we answered at nearly the exact same time haha. You also came to more or less the same conclusion. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out, and I learned some things. I was indeed trying to call a field attribute to concatenate to a string, what I really needed to do was call the "row" of the table under that field. A friend of mine helped with this, and most credit goes to them. This is the script that worked:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
cluster_field = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageNameField
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    row_object = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
    row_value = row_object.getValue(cluster_field.name)
    png_pathname = r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Geodata\Cluster Priority Maps/RANPriority {0}_{1}.png".format(pageNum, row_value)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, png_pathname, resolution=150)
del mxd
```